# AURA component with implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" not showing up on flow screens

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura, visual-flows, screen-flow

I have an aura component that has implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens", but won't show up in the flow builder, other AURA components show up, but not this new one.  Here is my AURA component.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="IBA_MultiSelectPicklist" access="global" >
    
    <aura:attribute name="labelText" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sourceLabel" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedLabel" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="valueText" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sourceObject" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sourceField" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="displayBox" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="incomingValues" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValues" type="String"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    
    <div>
        <lightning:dualListbox 
            name="name"
            label= "{!v.labelText}"
            sourceLabel="{!v.sourceLabel}"
            selectedLabel="{!v.selectedLabel}"
            options="{!v.options}"
            onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
            value="{!v.selectedValues}"
            
        />
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: It works for me with same code. What api version are you using?

Comment: @sanketkumar I have tried from 54-58.

Comment: @sanketkumar what version is your org, mine is winter 24.

Comment: same is mine. i am using release orgs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the patches must have fixed this issue because the file started showing up without me changing anything.